# To find all natural triples $(a, b, c)$ such that $2^c-1 \mid 2^a+2^b+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all positive integer triples $(a, b, c)$ such that $2^c-1 \mid 2^a+2^b+1$.

I have no important result on this one!

Comment: What happens when $a=2b+1$?  Note that this appears to be equivalent to when $a=b$...

Comment: You mean $a=2b-2$? To complete the square?

Comment: If $a,b$ are both even then the right hand is divisible by $3=2^2-1$, so that's an infinite list of examples.  Similarly, you can find congruences on $a,b$ which imply divisibility by $7$.

Comment: Yes that's a family of solutions! No I got no other example!

Comment: Well, like I say, if $a\equiv 1 \pmod 6, b\equiv 2 \pmod 6$ or conversely then the right hand is divisibly by $7=2^3-1$.  So that's another infinite family.  I expect there are lots and lots of them.

Comment: $c=3$ works whenever $a,b,0$ are pairwise non-congruent modulo three.

Comment: Maybe $c=2,3$ are the only cases though.  After all $2^c-1=1 +2+2^2+\cdots +2^{c-1}$ and $a\equiv a'\pmod {\varphi(2^c-1)}\implies 2^a\equiv 2^{a'}\pmod {2^c-1}$ so for $c>3$ you can't get to $0\pmod {2^c-1}$.

Comment: Correct, @lulu. I reached the same conclusion.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Ah, good.  I was just checking details.  Now I will just read yours!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appetizers from the comments:

- $c=1$ is left as an exercise
- $c=2$ works when both $a$ and $b$ are even
- $c=3$ works when $a,b$ and $0$ are pairwise non-congruent modulo $3$.

Then the main course:

**Claim.** There are no solutions with $c>3$.

**Proof.** We have trivially that if $a\equiv a'\pmod c$, then
$$
2^a\equiv2^{a'}\pmod{2^c-1}.
$$
Therefore without loss of generality we can assume that $0\le a,b<c$.
But in that case there are no solutions for larger $c$:

- If $a\neq b$ are distinct, then $2^a+2^b+2^0<2^c-1$ (observe that $2^c-1$ is the sum of $c>3$ distinct powers of two).
- If $a=b$, then it won't work. Either the sum $2^a+2^b+1$ is still $<2^c-1$, or $a=b=c-1$ and $2^a+2^b+1=2^c+1$.

Comment: Because $2^3-1=2^2+2^1+2^0$ that same congruence gives us the claim for $c=3$. It also follows that those are all the solutions when $c=3$.